# Best OS for Raspberry Pi that would support Remote Desktop aswell as local internet surfing

Tags: operating-systems

I've just ordered a Raspberry Pi and I'm interested to know what you think the best OS is for it that would:

- Support remote desktop so I can connect to my terminal server.
- And support local web browsing, with ideally flash player/html 5 browser so sites 
  like YouTube are accecssable.

  - Support user authentication so people can't just access my data

I'm not really sure what the best solution is, so any tips or suggestions would be greatfully received!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not much to choose from. Raspbian - the Foundation's recommended distribution - will suit all (most) your needs.

Forget about watching html5/flash videos on your browser, at least for now. There just is no acceleration there (yet?). You will be able to watch Youtube videos, but not the way you are used to - there is a Youtube video source plugin for XBMC (media center), where videos play quite nice, even at 1080p.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look at the plugin you mentioned as that sounds perfect. Thank you, Jake